# regex to match three letters and dash and 60 chars long

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to detect the following pattern in a string --- basically three capital letters and a dash, and the string should be 60 characters long.

`USR-` , `HEY-`, `TES-`, `HOY-`

I am trying lots of things but my regex knowledge leaves a bit to be desired. Sadly enough, the code below was as close as I have come. ‍♀️

Here is an example string which should match.

```js
const regex = /[A-Z]{3}-/;
const string = "USR-12345678912345678912345678912345678912345678912345678912";
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Comment: Please provide an example string input and expected output.

Comment: `/^[A-Z]{3}-.{56}$/`? Starts with 3 uppercase letters and a hyphen, then contains any 56 chars (other than line break chars).

Comment: `^[A-Z]{3}-\d{56}$` where `\d` stands for *digits*

Comment: in case of having to match more specific prefixes instead of a generic upper-case 3-letter-sequence ... [`/^(?:USR|HEY|TES|HOY)-[^\s]{56}$/`](https://regex101.com/r/7eFJXt/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
const regex = /^[A-Z]{3}-[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{56}$/
```

This way, remaining 56 characters can be either lower or capital letters, numbers or `_`, `.`, `-`.